# ZF2 partial loop error

Tags: layout, partial-views, zend-framework2

Moving my project from my local (osx) development to (debian) production put's me in some erros. Everything works wel on my local dev but on the debian two things goes wrong.

My layout.phtml won't render (no error) and I get this error for partial loops.

Paste of error output:

http://pastebin.com/74g1dL8g

Thanks! :)
nick

Answer (score 0):

As Error states.

`"Rows as part of this DataSource, with type object cannot be cast to an array"`.

You must have moved your database with structure only option without data. In your code somewhere, you have not place empty checks to verify dataset or records. I think it is trying to caste empty object into array....

You need to debug your application either using XDebug which provides step-by-step debugging, and can be used with eclipse PDT, netbeans and even vim.

Or

use old fashioned way

```
echo "programing working to till this line";
exit();
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for letting this know a bit lately but, I found out it's a kind of bug in ZF2. The loop failed at the point of inArray(). I solve this problem very easy by using directly a 'foreach' loop instead of using the partial